# Error Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is T? but Nothing was expected

Tags: generics, kotlin

```
class MyExample {
  abstract class Field<in E, T : Any>(private val getter: (E) -> T?) {
    fun get(entity: E): T? { return getter(entity) }
  }

  interface Meta<T: Any> {
    fun getFields(): List<MyExample.Field<T, *>>
  }


  interface MetaRepository {
    fun <T : Any> getMeta(klass: KClass<T>): Meta<T>?
  }

  lateinit var metaRepository: MetaRepository

  fun <T : Any> doSomthing(entity: T?) {

    val meta = metaRepository.getMeta(entity!!::class)!!

    meta.getFields().forEach { field ->
      val fieldValue = field.get(entity) // <-- Error Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is T? but Nothing was expected
      Unit
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why the compilation error `"Error Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is T? but Nothing was expected"` is produced for the code above?
How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at

```
val meta = metaRepository.getMeta(entity!!::class)!!
```

What type do you expect for `meta`? Probably `Meta<T>`. But if you try to annotate it, you'll see that's wrong. It's actually inferred to be `Meta<out T>` (basically because `entity` could actually belong to some subclass of `T`, so `entity!!::class` is `KClass<out T>`).

So `field` is `Field<Nothing, out Any>` and `field.get` needs `Nothing` as its argument.

The solution is [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) to get `KClass<T>` instead:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> doSomthing(entity: T?) {

    val meta = metaRepository.getMeta(T::class)!!

    meta.getFields().forEach { field ->
        val fieldValue = field.get(entity!!)
        // Unit at the end isn't needed
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `getMeta` itself can't use `reified` because it's an interface method and there's nothing to inline, but you can make a helper method to simplify calls to it:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> MetaRepository.getMeta1() = getMeta(T::class)

...
val meta = metaRepository.getMeta1<T>()!!
```

Side note: if you need `entity` not to be `null` anyway (using `entity!!`), there's probably no good reason to make its type `T?` instead of `T`.

Comment: This is an awesome explanation! Thank you so much!