# Problem to access a property via reflection with different kind of references in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I tried to read the value of a property via reflection in a complex scenario (with generics, etc.). But I always failed with this error:

`Type mismatch: inferred type is ReflectionTest.Person but Nothing was expected`

So I was able to narrow it down to the following problem:

```
class ReflectionTest {
    
    data class Person(val firstname: String, val lastname: String)

    @Test
    fun b() {
        val person = Person("Donald", "Duck")

        val a = Person::class       
        val b = person::class     

        val personAfirstname = a.memberProperties.find { it.name == "firstname" }?.get(person) // this works fine
        val personBfirstname = b.memberProperties.find { it.name == "firstname" }?.get(person) // compiler error: Type mismatch: inferred type is ReflectionTest.Person but Nothing was expected
    }
}
```

Can someone explain, why the compiler expects `Nothing` in the last line and how to fix this problem?

During my investigation, I came across [Error Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is T? but Nothing was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835404/error-kotlin-type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-t-but-nothing-was-expected) . But even with that, I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: val b = person::class    I think it should be val b = Person::class with a big P

Comment: "How to fix this problem?" can't really be answered because w don't know why you are getting a class from an expression in the first place. Why not just use `a` instead, which you *know* works?

Answer (score 2):

While the type of `Person::class` is `KClass<Person>`, the type of `person::class` is `KClass<out Person>`.

Unlike `TypeName::class`, which can only evaluate to one thing - the `KClass` representing `TypeName` - `expression::class` can evaluate to different `KClass` instances, depending on the runtime type of `expression`. For example:

```
fun foo(x: Any) {
    println(x::class)
}

fun main() {
    foo(Any()) // prints Any
    foo(1) // prints Int
    foo("bar") // prints String
}
```

The type of `x::class` can't be `KClass<Any>` (aka `Any::class`). `x` might be an instance of some other class at runtime. It has to be `KClass<out Any>`, because it might evaluate to `Int::class` (of type `KClass<Int>`), or `String::class` (of type `KClass<String>`), etc.

In your case, `Person` is a data class so it can't be inherited from, so `person` can't actually be an instance of *anything but* `Person`. Kotlin is not smart enough know this, so the type of `person::class` is `KClass<out Person>`, just like any other `expression::class` expressions.

So as far as Kotlin is concerned, `person::class` could be a class that is a subclass of `Person`, and so you cannot pass a `Person` when getting the value of a property you found from the class. After all, what if the `find` finds a property that is only available in a subclass of `Person`? (Of course, we humans know that will not happen.)

`expression::class` is analogous to Java's `Object.getClass` method. See also [Why does getClass return a Class<? extends |X|>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37796705/5133585) for a discussion on why `getClass` returns `Class<? extends T>` (analogous to `KClass<out T>`).